# I need to calculate a Date only when there are Term days

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, microsoft-lists

I need to Calculate a Term Deadline based on the expiration date BUT only when there are Term Days.
My current formula for "Term Deadline:

```
 =[Expiration Date]-[Term Days]
```

The problem is that the formula is calculated for all rows.  However, I only want it to populate when there are term days.

If Term days is blank I dont want to calculate a Term Deadline.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use formula like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Term Days]),"",[Expiration Date]-[Term Days])
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

Comment: OMG TYVM!!!!!!  you're the best xoxo

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked for you!